# Casting a pointer from a char in C

Tags: c

If I have a function that returns a `(char)` in c and I have a `(char* getSomething)` how do I cast it? It is giving me an error when I try to cast it through either `(char*)` or `(char*)&`

Example:
If the function is :

```
char* getSomething;
getSomething = getSth(var);
```

getSth return a char

Comment: If the function returns a `char`, there's absolutely no meaningfull way to cast it to a pointer `char *`. Clarify the problem. The way it is now, it just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store a value in a pointer.  A pointer points to a memory address where data is stored, so you must first store the returned character to a memory location (a character variable or malloc'ed region) which can then be pointed to by getSomething.

```
char *getSomething;
char something;

something = getSth(var);
getSomething = &something;
```

Or you can directly access the memory location with the pointer

```
char something;
char *getSomething = &something;

*getSomething = getSth(var);
```

Finally, you could use malloc to return a region of memory to point at and then store the returned value in this memory location.  Just make sure that you free this memory before the function exits.

```
char *getSomething = malloc(sizeof(char));

*getSomething = getSth(var);

free(getSomething);
```

Comment: when i do print getSomething it adds a char. For example if something was (e) it will tell me getSomething is (ed)

Comment: When you print make sure you are dereferencing the pointer, *getSomething: printf("%c\n", *getSomething); otherwise, it will print a byte of the memory address where the data is stored

Answer (score 0):

```
*getSomething = getSth(var);
```

Basically it says "put the char where getSomething points to..."

Comment: You'll want to allocate memory for that pointer before you store a char to it. Point it at some other char, or use malloc to allocate memory from the heap.

Comment: A good reminder! I assumed the memory was allocated because I didn't saw no #include either ;)